# Cross-Browser Coding: IE on Mac

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

Coding across browsers is one of the most desirable of front-end development skills.

What is the best way to check cross-browser coding for IE on a Mac?

Comment: Thank goodness you don't mean [IE for Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_for_Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link, try and Install, that will help you for CSS and JavaScript as per IE

[Internet Explorer for mac ie7 ie8 ie9](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/)